# misunderstanding array pointers passed to functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

Why don't the print statements in the function match the top level prints?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

void bar(float **foo)
{
  printf(" &foo[0][0]    %f \n", &foo[0][0]);
}

int main()
{
  float mat[5][5], **ptr;
  mat[0][0] = 3.0f;
  ptr = (float **)mat;
  printf("  mat[0][0]    %f \n",  mat[0][0]);
  printf(" &ptr[0][0]    %f \n", &ptr[0][0]);
  bar(ptr);
}
```

the results:

```
 mat[0][0]     3.000000 
 &ptr[0][0]    3.000000 
 &foo[0][0]    -0.005548
```

Comment: Why are you using &foo and &ptr?

Comment: I'm obviously doing this completely wrong...  All I'm trying to do is figure out how to pass a 2D float array to my function...

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Comment: Do it so: `void bar(float foo[5][])`

Answer (score 1):

You should print pointers using `%p`. not `%f`. Also, the cast `(float**)mat` doesn't make any sense.

When you say `&((float**)mat)[0][0]`, you actually look for a pointer in the address of `mat`. if pointers are wider than floats, you will read from some other bytes in the stack, and they can changed when you call functions.

Answer (score 1):

Several others have gotten you for what looks like confusion between `mat[0][0]` being of type `float` and `&ptr[0][0]` being of type `float *`, but you have another more subtle problem: ARRAYS ARE NOT POINTERS.

Normally arrays are a lot like pointers, but for very subtle reasons, `float [][]` is not compatible with `float **` the way `float []` and `float *` are.

In many contexts (such as being passed to a function), an array *decays* to a *pointer to its first element*. Thus, `mat` decays to `&mat[0]`. The type of an array `T []` decays to a pointer `T *`, which means that the type `mat` decays to (and the type of `&mat[0]`) is `float (*)[]` - that is, a pointer to an array of fixed size.

Here is the difference between a `float *` and a `float[]`:

```
float *     float[]
+-----+     +-----+-----+
| ptr | --> | 0.0 | 1.0 |
+-----+     +-----+-----+
```

Now here is the difference between a `float **` and a `float[][]`:

```
float **    float *[]   float[][]         float (*)[]
+-----+     +-----+     +-----+-----+     +-----+     (imagine this
| ptr | --> | ptr | --> | 0.0 | 1.0 | <-- | ptr |     pointing to
+-----+     +-----+     +-----+-----+     +-----+     the 0.0 cell)
            | ptr | --> | 2.0 | 3.0 |
            +-----+     +-----+-----+
```

Those types are, from left to right, pointer-to-pointer-to-`float`, array-of-pointers-to-`float`, array-of-arrays-of-`float`s, and pointer-to-array-of`float`s. The address of `&float[0]`, converted to a `float **`, gets dereferenced *twice as a pointer* even though there is only one pointer - the pointer to `float[0]` (and thus, the rest of the array). Any value you get through this is garbage.